# How to mask a raster using SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object?

Tags: polygon, raster, spatial, mask

I would like to mask a raster using all the polygons contained in a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" object.
Up until now i tried this:

```
r=raster("myraster.asc")
```

Then I got my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (called "vor_spdf") object with a list of 6 Polygons, so I runned:

```
typeof(vor_spdf) # It results in [1] "S4"
r1=crop(r,extent(vor_spdf))
r2=mask(r1,vor_spdf@polygons[[1]]) #Trying to mask the raster on the geometry of the first polygon
```

This is the error... `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "Polygons"’`

Do you have any suggestion on how to handle this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(raster)
library(terra)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")) |> raster()
```

Solution

```
m <- mask(r, p[1,])
```

---

But you are using outdated packages. You might be better off using "terra" instead.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

m <- mask(r, v[1,])
```